# Php tags within a variable error

Tags: php, mysql

i have been trying to write a php script, i want to add the php code within a variable which requires me to have the php tags within the variable but the following code gives me error because the php tags are getting executed.

here is the code

```
$current .= " <?php";
$current .= '$CONF = array();';
$current .= '$CONF["host"] = "'.$mysql_host.'";';
$current .= '$CONF["user"] = "'.$mysql_user.'";';                                   
$current .= '$CONF["pass"] = "'.$mysql_pass.'";';
$current .= '$CONF["name"] = "'.$mysql_base.'";';
$current .= "?> ";
file_put_contents("includes/config.php", $current);
```

Please help me out with this, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you put that in single line, it would be `$current .= " <?php$CONF = array();$CONF["host"] = "'.$mysql_host.'";......";`  do you think it's right ?

Comment: space is missing after <?php tag

Comment: There are spaces, The code looks like this:
https://imgur.com/ffdvthj

Comment: Are you sure your install.php file actually begins with a `<?php` tag? It looks like the interpreter thinks your php code starts within the string at the first line...

Comment: **Don't** generate PHP code by hand. It is tedious and error-prone. For example, if `$mysq_pass` contains quotes, the code you generate has syntax errors and it doesn't compile. Use [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) to produce valid PHP code for a data structure.

Comment: The whitespace in front of `<?php` in a file that is not meant to produce content is a common error that, in some contexts, produce the unexpected warning ["Cannot modify header information - headers already sent"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8028957/4265352). The same for the whitespace after `?>`. The closing PHP tag `?>` is not even needed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ***provide `space`*** in between first two line of code:-

```
$current .= "<?php"; 
$current .= ' $CONF = array();';
//-----------^give space here------
```

You can do in ***another way***

```
$current .= "<?php ";
//----------------^give space here------ 
$current .= '$CONF = array();';
```

***For better readability*** add new-line in each code-line like below:-

```
$current .= " <?php".PHP_EOL;
$current .= '$CONF = array();'.PHP_EOL;
$current .= '$CONF["host"] = "'.$mysql_host.'";'.PHP_EOL;
$current .= '$CONF["user"] = "'.$mysql_user.'";'.PHP_EOL;                                   
$current .= '$CONF["pass"] = "'.$mysql_pass.'";'.PHP_EOL;
$current .= '$CONF["name"] = "'.$mysql_base.'";'.PHP_EOL;
$current .= "?> ";
file_put_contents("config.php", $current);
```

Comment: @AshrithGovind no, it doesn't work. Use `$mysql_pass = 'abc"123';` and see how that part of the application that reads `include/config.php` suddenly stops working.

Answer (score 3):

**Do not** generate PHP code by hand. It is tedious and error-prone. For example, if `$mysq_pass` contains quotes, the code you put in `includes/config.php` has syntax errors and doesn't compile.

Use [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) to produce valid PHP code for a data structure:

```
$current = "<?php\n" .
    '$CONF = '.
    // var_export() produces valid code only for the array
    var_export(array(
        'host' => $mysql_host,
        'user' => $mysql_user,
        'pass' => $mysql_pass,
        'name' => $mysql_base,
    ), true).         // 'true' tells it to return the code, to not echo it
    // There is no need to use the PHP closing tag
    ";\n"
;

file_put_contents("includes/config.php", $current);
```

See it in action: https://3v4l.org/G5ZoX

Comment: Please mark this answer as it's correct for all scenario. My answer is correct only for current scenario (As OP didn't mention the variable values)